# PHP checking $_POST

Tags: php, post, arrays

I have some form fields that when a form is submitted creates an array within the $_POST, I needing to check the this array has atleast 4 keys, how can I check that? I have no idea

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try:

```
<?php 
if(count($_POST) >= 4):
//Do your stuff
else:
//Do your error stuff
endif;
```

If you want to check an array within $_POST as apose to $_POST itself use 

`count($_POST['name_of_key_to_array_you_want_to_count'])`

Answer (score 6):

First, to make your work easier, you should change input name into array version. Something like this should work:

```
<input type='text' name='data[]' value='' />
```

Then, PHP will do it's magic and all you have to do is:

```
echo count($_POST['data']);
```

This is because your `data[]` form field is changed into array.

Comment: Sounds closest to what he's actually asking: length of array within $_POST, rather than length of $_POST.

Answer (score 2):

Use **[`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)** and **[`count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)**:

```
echo count(array_keys($_POST));
```

Or simply:

```
echo count($_POST);
```

because keys are same in number as items.

Answer (score 0):

The [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function returns the length of an array.